# do we have to interrupt the background thread in ondestroy method?

Tags: android

I am running a background thread that runs all through out the life cycle of application. Do we need to interrupt this thread in onDestroy method? or is it handled by android system? If we don't interrupt manually, will it lead to memory leaks?

Comment: You are talking about the onDestroy of an activity? If that is the case, you are missusing the activity. If you have some background task that should run in the background, not directly related to UI, you should use a Service class

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that my background thread updates UI.

Comment: So, its a good practice to cancel any task if there is something pending in on destroy, as, depending on how your code is made, you may keep a reference of that activity until the thread is gone. Android will not take care of finishing that thread, since the context where it executes its the same linux process (aca Application instance). Think of your execution as a sandbox linux process where you execute your actions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to finish your pending tasks when the activity is gone, since basically whatever the thread does will not have impact for the user as it won't modify the UI.

Regarding memory leaks, android apps run in a linux process, so the context of the threads is the application, not the activity, that is why, when an activity is gone, your thread will keep running and you may update a death object. It's a good practice to stop it to avoid a memory leak because you keep a reference to what you want to update (of course, unless you use a `WeakReference`).